# HardHat: Nothing to compile

Tags: npm, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

When compiling the hardhat project When it's showing **Nothing to Compile**.

```
{
  "name": "HardhAtToken",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.6",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.6.6",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.6-dev.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "glob": "^7.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share steps to reproduce the issue. Do you have any `*.sol` files in the `contracts` directory? Have you made any changes to them since the last compile? What is the exact command (including its options) that you run when you want to compile the contracts?

Comment: ng@ram:/media/ngsharma/Ethereum/Solidity-workspace/DemoHardHat/contract$ npx hardhat compile
**Nothing to compile**

Comment: yes ** *.sol ** files in the contract directory.No any changes to the last compile. exact command is **npx hardhat compile**

Answer (score 7):

Hardhat keeps a cache of compiled contracts in the `cache` project folder.

The `npx hardhat compile` command only compiles files that have not been changed since the last compilation. So the "nothing to compile" message is expected in your case.

You can either clear the cache using `npx hardhat clean`, or force recompilation of cached sources using the `npx hardhat compile --force` argument.

Docs: https://hardhat.org/guides/compile-contracts.html

Answer (score 3):

The major issue with that you haven't created a ***contracts*** directory in your code.Then you can implement sol file in it and run npx hardhat compile..It was worked for me...